# global legend for all subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I create an n x n matrix of matplot subplots which contain the same type of curve (lets name them signal1 and signal2):

```
n=5
f, axarr = plt.subplots(n,n)
for i,signal_generator in enumerate(signal_generators):
  y=i%n
  x=(i-y)/n
  axarr[x, y].plot(signal_generator.signal1)
  axarr[x, y].plot(signal_generator.signal2)
```

Since the 2 signals in each subplot each represent the same types, I want to use a figure global legend with the two entries 'signal1' 'signal2', rather then attaching the same legend to each subplot.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 19):

One way to do it is to force some extra space below the plots.  Then you can fit the legend right there and have one "global" legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close('all')

fig, axlist = plt.subplots(3, 3)
for ax in axlist.flatten():
    line1, = ax.plot(np.random.random(100), label='data1')
    line2, = ax.plot(np.random.random(100), label='data2')
    line3, = ax.plot(np.random.random(100), 'o', label='data3')

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.12)  # create some space below the plots by increasing the bottom-value
axlist.flatten()[-2].legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.12), ncol=3)
# it would of course be better with a nicer handle to the middle-bottom axis object, but since I know it is the second last one in my 3 x 3 grid...

fig.show()
```

Now there will be an label below the second last (bottom middle) axis area, thanks to the `bbox_to_anchor=(x, y)` with a negative y-value.  Depending on how many different subplots you have, and how many different lines you plot in each subplot it might be better to keep proper track of the different line-objects.  Maybe append them to a list.

For me it the output figure looks like

[image]

Does this give you want you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your help - the solution I came up with, was adding the legend just to the first subplot. But yours is much better and cleaner.