# How to check if object is of type "matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection"

Tags: python, matplotlib, object-type

For a specific task ( [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956501/global-legend-for-subplots-with-different-content) ) I want to check if an object is a:

```
matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection
```

or a:

```
matplotlib.lines.Line2D
```

object.

I tired it like this:

```
 if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection):
```

but this did not work. If would want to test if two variables h and handles are of the same type how would I check them both to be either *matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection* or *matplotlib.lines.Line2D* objects?

**Edit1**

Here is the code in question which adapts the solution in the above link:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math


def is_inlist(handle, handles):
    for h in handles:
        if h.get_color() == handle.get_color() and \
            h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle() and \
            h.get_marker() == handle.get_marker():
            return True
    return False


lines=[]
labels=[]
legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':10}  
# Example data


mu = 0
mu2 = 5
variance = 1
variance2 = 2
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
sigma2 = math.sqrt(variance2)
x = np.linspace(mu-3*variance,mu+3*variance, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(mu2-3*variance2,mu2+3*variance2, 100)

nrows = 4
# Plot

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(5, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0001)
#fig.suptitle("Stacked Plots with global Legend which contains to little elements",fontsize=14,weight='bold')


axis[0].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[0].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[1].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='yellow',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[1].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[2].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[2].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)


axis[3].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+5.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='violet',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK6", interpolate=True)
axis[3].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)







for i in range(nrows):
    h, l = axis[i].get_legend_handles_labels()
    for hi, li in zip(h,l):
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
            lines.append(hi)
            labels.append(li)
           




#x for x in item if x not in Z










            
# only 3 Legend entrys Label1 , Label2 and Label3 are visible .. Differences in cloors and markers are ignored
plt.legend(handles=lines, labels=labels,bbox_to_anchor=(0., nrows+.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=3, prop=legend_properties,mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False,framealpha=0.0) 


plt.show()
```

unfortunately it gives me the error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "PATH..../.py", line 76, in <module>
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
      File "PATH..../.py", line 9, in is_inlist
        if h.get_color() == handle.get_color() and \
    AttributeError: 'PolyCollection' object has no attribute 'get_color'
```

I was suggested to do a case analysis for each type of matplotlib object. This is where I struggle.
I wanted to change the "is_inlist" function and to work for different cases. but the case analysis itself does not work yet:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math


def is_inlist(handle, handles):
    for h in handles:
        if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) and isinstance(h, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection):
            if h.get_color() == handle.get_color() and \
                h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle() and \
                h.get_marker() == handle.get_marker():
                return True
        if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.lines.Line2D) and isinstance(h, matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
            if h.get_color() == handle.get_color() and \
                h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle() and \
                h.get_marker() == handle.get_marker():
                return True        
                
                
    return False


lines=[]
labels=[]
legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':10}  
# Example data


mu = 0
mu2 = 5
variance = 1
variance2 = 2
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
sigma2 = math.sqrt(variance2)
x = np.linspace(mu-3*variance,mu+3*variance, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(mu2-3*variance2,mu2+3*variance2, 100)

nrows = 4
# Plot

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(5, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0001)
#fig.suptitle("Stacked Plots with global Legend which contains to little elements",fontsize=14,weight='bold')


axis[0].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[0].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[1].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='yellow',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[1].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[2].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[2].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)


axis[3].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+5.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='violet',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK6", interpolate=True)
axis[3].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)



for i in range(nrows):
    h, l = axis[i].get_legend_handles_labels()
    for hi, li in zip(h,l):
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
            lines.append(hi)
            labels.append(li)
           





# only 3 Legend entrys Label1 , Label2 and Label3 are visible .. Differences in cloors and markers are ignored
plt.legend(handles=lines, labels=labels,bbox_to_anchor=(0., nrows+.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=3, prop=legend_properties,mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False,framealpha=0.0) 


plt.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Path/.. .py", line 84, in <module>
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
      File "Path/.. .py", line 9, in is_inlist
        if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) and isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection):
    NameError: global name 'matplotlib' is not defined
```

**Edit2**

I added:

```
import matplotlib.collections
```

as I was suggested

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
import matplotlib.collections

def is_inlist(handle, handles):
    for h in handles:
        if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) and isinstance(h, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection):
            if h.get_facecolor() == handle.get_facecolor() and \
                h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle() and \
                h.get_alpha() == handle.get_alpha():
                return True
        if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.lines.Line2D) and isinstance(h, matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
            if h.get_color() == handle.get_color() and \
                h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle() and \
                h.get_marker() == handle.get_marker():
                return True        
                
                
    return False


lines=[]
labels=[]
legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':10}  
# Example data


mu = 0
mu2 = 5
variance = 1
variance2 = 2
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
sigma2 = math.sqrt(variance2)
x = np.linspace(mu-3*variance,mu+3*variance, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(mu2-3*variance2,mu2+3*variance2, 100)

nrows = 4
# Plot

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(5, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0001)
#fig.suptitle("Stacked Plots with global Legend which contains to little elements",fontsize=14,weight='bold')


axis[0].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[0].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[1].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='yellow',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[1].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[2].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[2].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)


axis[3].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+5.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='violet',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK6", interpolate=True)
axis[3].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)



for i in range(nrows):
    h, l = axis[i].get_legend_handles_labels()
    for hi, li in zip(h,l):
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
            lines.append(hi)
            labels.append(li)
           





# only 3 Legend entrys Label1 , Label2 and Label3 are visible .. Differences in cloors and markers are ignored
plt.legend(handles=lines, labels=labels,bbox_to_anchor=(0., nrows-1+.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=3, prop=legend_properties,mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False,framealpha=0.0) 


plt.show()
```

The error I get now is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Path/.. .py", line 80, in <module>
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
      File "Dath/.. .py", line 10, in is_inlist
        if h.get_facecolor() == handle.get_facecolor() and \
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**solution**  based on the explanation of ImportanceOfBeingErnest:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math
import matplotlib.collections

def is_inlist(handle, handles):
    for h in handles:
        if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection) and isinstance(h, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection): 
            if np.all(h.get_facecolor() == handle.get_facecolor()) and \
                np.all(h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle()) and \
                np.all(h.get_alpha() == handle.get_alpha()):
                return True
        elif isinstance(handle, matplotlib.lines.Line2D) and isinstance(h, matplotlib.lines.Line2D):
            if h.get_color() == handle.get_color() and \
                h.get_linestyle() == handle.get_linestyle() and \
                h.get_marker() == handle.get_marker():
                return True        
                
                
    return False


lines=[]
labels=[]
legend_properties = {'weight':'bold','size':10}  
# Example data


mu = 0
mu2 = 5
variance = 1
variance2 = 2
sigma = math.sqrt(variance)
sigma2 = math.sqrt(variance2)
x = np.linspace(mu-3*variance,mu+3*variance, 100)
x2 = np.linspace(mu2-3*variance2,mu2+3*variance2, 100)

nrows = 4
# Plot

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(5, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0001)
#fig.suptitle("Stacked Plots with global Legend which contains to little elements",fontsize=14,weight='bold')


axis[0].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[0].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[0].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[1].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[1].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='yellow',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[1].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)

axis[2].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='orange',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[2].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[2].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)


axis[3].fill_between(x+6,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='green',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK1", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+4,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='purple',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK2", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+3,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='blue',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK3", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+7,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='red',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK4", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+6.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='#73d216',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK5", interpolate=True)
axis[3].fill_between(x+5.5,0,mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma), color='violet',alpha=0.5,label="PEAK6", interpolate=True)
axis[3].plot(x2,2.5*mlab.normpdf(x2, mu2, sigma2),color='black',linestyle="",label="Exp", marker="o", markersize=4)



for i in range(nrows):
    h, l = axis[i].get_legend_handles_labels()
    for hi, li in zip(h,l):
        if not is_inlist(hi, lines):
            lines.append(hi)
            labels.append(li)
           





# only 3 Legend entrys Label1 , Label2 and Label3 are visible .. Differences in cloors and markers are ignored
plt.legend(handles=lines, labels=labels,bbox_to_anchor=(0., nrows-1+.02, 1., .102), loc=3,ncol=3, prop=legend_properties,mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False,framealpha=0.0) 


plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how it didn't work?  That's the usual method of type checking.

Comment: `if isinstance(handle, matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection):` is entirely correct. "But it did not work" is not a proper problem description. Always provide a [mcve]!

Comment: Show your `import ...` lines, regarding `PolyCollection`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a MWE with the error i get.

Comment: @Norrin In your code `matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection` is undefined. You need to `import matplotlib.collections`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnes i did what you suggest and now i get an error message i do not understand at all? Why does this return "array with more than one element is ambiguous" . The attribute i ask for is just the color?

Comment: Well, too much questions within the same post, too much "edit", title and questions are barely not related, please try to be focused on **one single** question and don't ask for SO community to debug your code line by line

Comment: I honestly thought the solution i am searching in the other question ,while dealing with the same problem, is conceptually different enough to be also interesting for others at some point. If this is not the case and the etiquette on this forum requite me to delete it, than i will delete it immediately . I appreciate the fact that people take the time to actually look at my question in any environment. I seriously do not understand the error above . Hence i asked.

Comment: @Arount has a valid point here. You keep asking question after question, editing the questions several times, also asking questions in parallel without waiting for a solution on one of them coming up. The way SO is meant to be used is not actually as a help center, where you walk in and let others solve all your problems, but rather as a Q&A site. You ask a clear and consise quesiton; someone gives an answer. This also means that you should spend some time preparing the question in such a way that it *can*  be answered.

Comment: To make it obvious: Imagine you google (or duckduckgo) _How to check if object is of type “matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection”_ and end here. Do you think you will find your answer easily? I'm not - This is the whole purpose of SO: Have the best answer with the smallest amount of time / effort.

Comment: I read through a number of different posts as i try to gather some of the vast knowledge in this site and always found those posts to be most helpfull were the full developement of the solution was visible hence with every **Edit** i always added something but never deleted anything. I thought this would be a good idea . Apparently not. I really appreciate your feedback how i am being perceived and i will try to avoid this behavior in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the initial problem is to actually import the module which provides the class for comparisson.

You simply lack `import matplotlib.collections`.

The next error is actually pretty self-explanatory. It says that it's impossible to compare two arrays.

So let's say the
facecolor of `h` is `[[ 0., 0.50196078, 0., 0.5]]` and the
facecolor of `handle` is  `[[ 1., 0.64705882, 0., 0.5]]`, then
`h.get_facecolor() == handle.get_facecolor()` results in 
`[[False False  True  True]]`

Now, is two times false and two times true true or false? One cannot know. Therefore you need to use either `any()` or `all()` to decide if you want to know if any of the elements is True or if all of the elements are True.

Here you would want to check for the same color, thus use `all`:

```
np.all(h.get_facecolor() == handle.get_facecolor())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If i may ask a related question: `np.array_equal(h.get_facecolor(),handle.get_facecolor())` or `np.allclose(h.get_facecolor(),handle.get_facecolor(), rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08 )` also seem to work . Is there an inherent advantage to one of theses comparisons?

Comment: In view of the application here, I don't see any difference.

Comment: Out of interest can the np.all() function also be used to compare a single itemi`hi` to each entry in an array or list `l` like `if  np.all( l == hi) : ` ?

Comment: You can use `np.all()` to compare a single item to a numpy array. This does not work for usual python lists.

Comment: Unfortunately i fund a small bug . The function `is_inlist` disregards any entry's with different names but with a color that already exists. I would like to fix this. If make pass this functon also `line` and `lines` and add  `elif label not in labels: return False` to me everything seems fine. But i am not sure if i am missing something.

Comment: At the end what matters is that it works for you. So try it out and if it's giving you the result you want, use it.